# codeigniter routing general understanding

Tags: codeigniter

I tried to understand how the routing in CodeIgniter work.

I want to use normal access to sides which are not a kind of user area or something special - only normals links in the main root of the website.

So I try this.

I've set in the `routes.php`

```
$route['/']  = "index";
```

I've created controller names `Frontend.php` and a model named `Frontend_modell.php`

The Controller (nothing to do)

```
 public function index()
    {
        redirect(site_url('index'));
    }
```

The Modell

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();        
    }
```

I've added an `index.php` inside the view-folder `Frontend` and I add the `index.php` (for test) in the main folder from appilation and in the view folder.

If I try to access `www.domain.com` I see the URL will change to `www.domain.com/index`, but no side will come up. "the page you requested was not found."

What I do wrong ? I hope somebody can explain to me how it works correctly and why.

Answer (score 0):

First of all routes uses `controller_name/method_name` and here you tried to use `method_name` directly.

Secondly, most of cases you don't need to play with routes unless you need a special handler or rerouting, so mostly keep it to default.

Btw the url rerouted to `www.domain.com/index` cause it looked for a controller named `index` as you specified and there in no controller found with that name it should be `frontend` if that's your controller.

Comment: sorry i've done a mistake in my post, i post the wrong code for controller and modell - so what i have to change to access the index.php in the mainfolder or in the view/frontend folder?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean? .. please try to explain in more details.

Comment: what i have to do in controller/modell/routes to reach the index.php file inside my mainfolder

Comment: You want a complete explanation of how codeigniter works and how it renders the views?

Comment: I suggest you work through the [official tutorial](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html)

Comment: Do as @DFriend suggested, work through the documentations and follow any tutorial on youtube and make yourself familiar with the framework first then if you faced a problem ask here.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the problem was from another point.

The Controller i've create had some bugs, after checking the function of the CR Controller, the routing works fine :-))